# How do I click a javascript "link" using rselenium to start downloading excel file?

Tags: javascript, r, click, rselenium

I'm a beginner in R and I've been trying to scrape the following website:

https://sinca.mma.gob.cl/cgi-bin/APUB-MMA/apub.htmlindico2.cgi?page=pageFrame&header=Las%20Condes&macropath=./RM/D13/Cal/0001&macro=0001.diario.diario&from=970508&to=090312&

to automatically start downloading an excel file from this air monitoring station here in Chile. However, I noticed that using `SelectorGadget` the download link couldn't be selected and found out it was because the link was a javascript link `(href="javascript:Open('xcl');">Excel CSV)` as seen in the image below.

[image]

My question is there any way I can simulate a click on that javascript link? I've already simulated clicks for other parts of the same website succesfully but they where not javascript links. This is what I've already tried:

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)


rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4040L, verbose=F)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]


remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://sinca.mma.gob.cl/cgi-bin/APUB-MMA/apub.htmlindico2.cgi?page=pageFrame&header=Las%20Condes&macropath=./RM/D13/Cal/0001&macro=0001.diario.diario&from=970508&to=090312&")
Sys.sleep(5) # give the page time to fully load


# click on excel link to start downloading file (doesnt work) ------------

xls <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/label/span[3]/a")
xls$clickElement()
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/label/span[3]/a


##### TESTING

remDr$navigate("https://sinca.mma.gob.cl/cgi-bin/APUB-MMA/apub.htmlindico2.cgi?page=pageFrame&header=Las%20Condes&macropath=./RM/D13/Cal/0001&macro=0001.diario.diario&from=970508&to=090312&")
excel <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", "[href*=javascript]")
#excel <- remDr$findElement(using = "css selector", '[href*="javascript:Open('xcl')"]')
excel$highlightElement() # to visually check what elemnet is selected


remDr$closeServer()
remDr$close()
```

My objective is to be able to click the link and start downloading the excel file. I've been trying to do this for a couple days and I'm stuck, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is inside a frame that is inside a frameset. You first need to switch to that frame via the parent frameset, using RSelenium. You can use the frame ids `frMain` and `right` to target the elements to switch to. Then you should be able to simply target that `href` by using a css attribute = value selector of `[href*=xcl]`. The `*` is the *contains* operator specifying that the `href` attribute value of the target contains the substring `xcl`.

Something like the following (not tested):

```
frame_set <- remDr$findElement("css", "#frMain")
remDr$switchToFrame(frame_set)

child_frame <- remDr$findElement("css", "#right")
remDr$switchToFrame(child_frame)

csv_download <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "[href*=xcl]")
csv_download$clickElement()
```

---

You can use browser dev tools <kbd>F12</kbd> to view that path:

[image]